# Magento 2 Klarna checkout with paypal express payment issue

Tags: magento2, paypal-express, klarna, magento231, klarnacheckout

I am using magento version 2.3.1

I get issue when I place order with Klarna checkout
using Paypal express checkout

When place order its redirect on Paypal and pay now there
after that its giving error

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. %1

on review page (https://mydomain/paypal/express/review/)

when i check payment.log showing log like that

```
'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-2Y5123450M36524K',
    'SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED' => 'false',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-11-28T08:02:30Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '6123a5f92a775',
    'ACK' => 'Failure',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '5312345',
    'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10730',
    'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Shipping Address Postal Code Empty',
    'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The field Shipping Address Postal Code is required',
    'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
  ),
```

But i sure I have to add post code as well in shipping/billing zipcode field

I need to use Klarna checkout + paypal express payment method

any one help here, thanks in advance

Comment: Does Klarna works for you Pradipbhai, I am getting 403 error with fresh Magento itself v2.4.1

Comment: did you solve this issue? If yes, what was the root cause?